# How to use the cssSelector :nth-child(n) to locate element in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm using Python Selenium to locate element by using nth-child(n).

Below is my html code:

```
<div id="iopop" style="">
 <div style="" class="">
  <div id="iopoph" class="animated zoomIn" style=" ">
      <span style="" class="gs_hover"></span>
      <b class="in">FALAFEL</b>
      <a iid="128-73" class="itemsub lowend" price="2.99" name="FALAFEL (6)" style="">
          <b class="in">(6)</b>
          <b class="is"></b>
          <b class="ip">2.99</b>
          <b class="iq"></b></a>
      <a iid="128-74" class="itemsub lowend" price="4.99" name="FALAFEL (12)" style="">
          <b class="in">(12)</b>
          <b class="is"></b>
          <b class="ip">4.99</b>
          <b class="iq"></b>
      </a>
      <b class="is"></b>
      <b class="ip"></b>
      <b class="iq"></b>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to locate the first **a tag** by using nth-child(n) so I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#iopoph a:nth-child(2)').click()
```

But there is an error says:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div#iopoph a:nth-child(2)"}
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: To locate first `<a>` tag you can use `:nth-of-type` instead: `'div#iopoph a:nth-of-type(1)'`

Comment: The first a is the third child, so a:nth-child(3)

Answer (score 1):

You were close but you need to consider a couple of things:

- `div#iopoph` will identify the parent node, i.e.

  ```
  <div id="iopop" style="">
  ```
- So you need to traverse to it's grand child node:

  ```
  <div id="iopoph" class="animated zoomIn" style=" ">
  ```
- To locate it's child elements you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Locating `<a iid="128-73" class="itemsub lowend" price="2.99" name="FALAFEL (6)" style="">`:

    ```
    div.animated.zoomIn#iopoph a:nth-of-type(1)
    ```
  - Locating `<a iid="128-74" class="itemsub lowend" price="4.99" name="FALAFEL (12)" style="">`:

    ```
    div.animated.zoomIn#iopoph a:nth-of-type(2)
    ```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this locator a:nth-of-type(2)

Answer (score 1):

In your case example-
`div#iopop a:nth-child(3) -> returns first a <anchor> tag i.e. <a iid="128-73"`

`div#iopop a:nth-child(4) -> returns second a <anchor> tag i.e. <a iid="128-74"`

**nth-child(index):**
nth-child(index) method is used to select/get specified index child element.  But the specified index element should be same as mentioned before colon ( : ). 
 In your case-
`div#iopoph a:nth-child(2)`-> It points to tag  and it is not same as the tag you mentioned before : (colon). so it returns NOSUCHELEMENTEXCEPTION